# imacros - ignore code if tag not found

Tags: javascript, if-statement, imacros

```
URL GOTO=my site
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:login ATTR=NAME:name CONTENT=name
SET !ENCRYPTION NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:PASSWORD FORM=NAME:login ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=pass
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:login ATTR=ID:s1
WAIT SECONDS=3
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=image.jpg WAIT=YES
TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:*captcha* CONTENT=EVENT:SAVEPICTUREAS
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAB OPEN
TAB T=2
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
URL GOTO=site of service
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=... ATTR=NAME:username CONTENT=...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=ACTION:... ATTR=NAME:password CONTENT=...
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:FILE FORM=ACTION:... ATTR=NAME:pict CONTENT=image.jpg
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:SUBMIT FORM=ACTION:... ATTR=VALUE:Send
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG POS=6 TYPE=TD ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET !CLIPBOARD {{!EXTRACT}}
tab close
TAB T=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=INPUT:TEXT FORM=NAME:login ATTR=ID:recaptcha_response_field CONTENT={{!CLIPBOARD}}
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON FORM=NAME:login ATTR=ID:s1
WAIT SECONDS=3
```

I use this code to solve the CAPTCHA ..

Sometimes there is no CAPTCHA ..

I want to make this code only works if there is CAPTCHA ..

In the case of non-appearance of CAPTCHA (or image to save) ignores the following lines ..

I heard that this is possible through Javascript ..

But I can not find a way to do that ..

Any Help? ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use JavaScript.

Basically, what you need to do is check whether the captcha field do exists or not. Maybe something like this one.

```
function isCaptchaExists() {
    var macro = "TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=HREF:*captcha* EXTRACT=HTM";
    var retcode = iimPlayCode(macro);

    return retcode < 0;
}
```

Comment: I already use this command
But I'm looking for to learn more about using JavaScript with Imacros
For this code and other codes
thank you for replying and wanna you can help me with learning more about use javascript with imacros

Comment: @m0ro I updated my answer. But first, you need to familiarize yourself with iMacros using JavaScript.

Comment: how to do that ?
from where i can start ?
i want to learn from beginning
starting from learn the meaning of every word in java code and how to convert .imm code to java js code
thanks for interesting and i wish you give me more information